# How does jenkins pick a node dynamically from a label?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I wanted to understand how Jenkins picks up node dynamically in a given label. Suppose I have a label in which the following nodes are present.
user1-1.1.1.1
user2-1.1.1.1
user3-1.1.1.1
user1-2.2.2.2
user2-2.2.2.2
user3-2.2.2.2

How does it pick up the node from the above list ?

Is it like user1-1.1.1.1, user1-2.2.2.2, user2-1.1.1.1 , user2-2.2.2.2?
or
Is it like user1-1.1.1.1, user2-1.1.1.1, user3-1.1.1.1 ?
or
Does it pick up randomly?

Comment: Could you give a detail please. Is "user1-1.1.1.1" a node name ? As I know, it picks randomly for matching nodes. (You also can give labels with regex to matching nodes.)

Comment: @Tolqiu That's how we have named our nodes(username-ip). Can you please detail on how to match using regex?

Answer (score 0):

Defines a logical expression which determines which agents may execute builds of this project. This expression, when tested against the name and labels of each available agent, will be either true or false. If the expression evaluates to true, then that agent will be allowed to execute builds of this project.
A label expression can be as simple as entering a single label or agent name, for example *android-builder*, or *linux-machine-42*.
You can also make use of various operators to create more complex expressions.

For example, you can use "windows && jdk9" expression in your jobs to run on windows slaves with jdk9. You have to tag(label) your nodes(slaves) appropriate way.(windows, jdk9)